# Show that if $\alpha \underline \in \gamma$ and $\alpha \underline \in \delta$ for all $\alpha \in C$, then $\delta \underline \in \gamma$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\delta=sup\ C$ where $C$ is a set of ordinals. Let $\gamma$ be an ordinal. Show that if $\alpha \underline \in \gamma$  and $\alpha \underline \in \delta$ for all $\alpha \in C$, then $\delta \underline \in \gamma$.

I have tried to solve this, but I just cannot understand how to do it. I know that if it is transitive, then $\alpha \underline \in \delta$ and $\delta \underline \in \gamma$ will lead to $\alpha \underline \in \gamma$.

I have looked up that if $\beta \in \delta$ and $\beta \in \alpha$, then $\beta \in \gamma$ because $\alpha \underline \in \gamma$, then it should lead to $\delta \underline \in \gamma$, but I do not know why.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a readily available "is element in or equal to" symbol. But why not just use $\leq$?

Comment: $\alpha \underline \in \gamma$ should work -- that is \alpha \underline \in \gamma

Comment: How do you define $sup C$? Isn't what you're trying to prove equivalent?

Comment: I have used $\displaystyle \cup C$ for the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

$\delta$ is an ordinal since the union of ordinals is an ordinal.

For any two ordinals, $\alpha,\beta$, $\alpha\underline\in\beta\iff\alpha\subseteq\beta$.

Since for all $\alpha\in C,\alpha\underline\in\gamma(\iff\alpha\subseteq\gamma),$ we get $\delta=\bigcup C\subseteq\gamma(\iff\delta\underline\in\gamma)$

Comment: So, as $\alpha \in C$ and $\alpha \underline \in \gamma$ we have that $\cup C \underline \in \gamma$. But what is the relation between $C$ and $\cup C$, and how do we get that as $\alpha \underline \in \delta$ also exists.